# Sieve formula of Eratosthenes

Tags: number-theory

Let $P=\prod_{p\leq\sqrt{x}}p$ Then $\sqrt{x}<n\leq x$ is prime $\iff$ $(n,P)=1$

Then $\pi(x)-\pi(\sqrt{x})+1=\sum_{n\leq x}\delta((n,P))$ Now the book I am reading says
$\sum_{n\leq x}\delta((n,P))=\sum_{d|P}\mu(d)\lfloor\frac{x}{d}\rfloor$ and I am not sure where this comes from.
$$\sum_{n\leq x}\delta((n,P))=\sum_{n\leq x}\sum_{d|(n,P)}\mu(d)$$
Comes from mobius inversion. I do not see how this is equal to $\sum_{d|P}\mu(d)\lfloor\frac{x}{d}\rfloor$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n\le x}\sum_{d|\gcd(n,P)}\mu(d)=\sum_{n\le x}\sum_{\substack {d|n\\d|P}}\mu(d)$$
and by replacing $n=dm$ we have the above equals to $$\sum_{d|P}\sum_{m\le x/d}\mu(d)=\sum_{d|P}\mu(d)\left[\dfrac{x}{d}\right]$$